# Can you deduct mileage on your return trip home?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, irs

So super easy and newb question here. All the stuff I've read regarding having a dedicated home office and deducting mileage to client meetings, etc is all understandable. But what I don't understand is can you deduct the mileage on your return trip home or is it just to the client meeting etc.

I think it says you can deduct return trips here https://www.irs.gov/publications/p463/ch04.html but for some reason most articles i read say nothing about it lol. Is this just supposed to be obvious and understood? If so, then I'm an idiot cause i didn't find it obvious. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's kindof assumed that if you have to go to the client, you're not staying there forever. You deduct your mileage for the whole trip, including the part where you actually have to leave there and go back.

Comment: Ok thanks. I kind of figured this just wanted to make sure.  I started using an app to track my mileage and it asks to put reason for trip going from client to home and it got me thinking.  Should I put client meeting even though that's already happened, i'm just returning home. lol

Comment: It asks because if you run a personal errand on the way back you have to account for that. You also may be going to another client, so you only have to drive to that location once.